# Configuring Macports (Non-root)

Tags: macports

I am trying to install Macports as non-root and while following the installation instructions on the website:

```
tar -jxf MacPorts-2.2.0.tar.bz2 && cd MacPorts-2.2.0
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin ./configure \
    --enable-readline \
    --prefix=$HOME/macports \
    --with-install-user=`id -un` \
    --with-install-group=`id -gn` \
    --with-tclpackage=$HOME/macports/share/macports/Tcl
```

I encounter the following warning:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-tclpackage
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to make this warning go away. It appears that this causes a problem when I try to "make install":

```
===> making install in vendor
===> making install in vendor/tcl8.5.15/unix
Installing libtcl8.5.dylib to /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/
Installing tclsh as /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/bin/tclsh8.5
Installing tclConfig.sh to /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/
Installing libtclstub8.5.a to /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/
Installing message catalog files to /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/tcl8.5/msgs/
Installing header files to /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/include/
Installing library files to /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/tcl8.5/
Installing package http1.0 files to /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/tcl8.5/http1.0/
Installing package http 2.7.12 as a Tcl Module
Installing package opt0.4 files to /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/tcl8.5/opt0.4/
Installing package msgcat 1.5.2 as a Tcl Module
Installing package tcltest 2.3.5 as a Tcl Module
Installing package platform 1.0.12 as a Tcl Module
Installing package platform::shell 1.1.4 as a Tcl Module
Installing encoding files to /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/tcl8.5/encoding/
===> making install-tclthread in vendor/thread2.7.0
 /bin/sh ./tclconfig/install-sh -c  -m 555 libthread2.7.0.dylib /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/thread2.7.0/libthread2.7.0.dylib
 : /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/thread2.7.0/libthread2.7.0.dylib
 Install ttrace.tcl /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/thread2.7.0/ttrace.tcl
 Install pkgIndex.tcl /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/thread2.7.0
Installing header files in /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/include
Installing ./generic/tclThread.h
===> making install in vendor/tcllib-1.15
/Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/bin/tclsh8.5 `echo ./installer.tcl` \
        -pkg-path   /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/tcllib1.15 \
        -no-examples -no-html -no-nroff \
        -no-wait -no-gui -no-apps
Installing Tcllib 1.15
You have chosen the following configuration ...

Packages:      /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/tcllib1.15
Applications:  Not installed.
Examples:      Not installed.
Documentation: Not installed.

..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Generating /Users/law978/macports/libexec/macports/lib/tcllib1.15/pkgIndex.tcl

===> making install in doc
/usr/bin/install -c -d -o law978 -g 419502728 -m 0755 "/Users/law978/macports"
/usr/bin/install -c -d -o law978 -g 419502728 -m 0755 "/Users/law978/macports/etc/macports"
< prefix.mtree /usr/sbin/mtree -U -e -p "/Users/law978/macports" > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the user and group ID manually you can also use `--with-no-root-privileges`. The `--with-tclpackage` flag is no longer needed starting with MacPorts 2.2.

Your output does not contain an error message, so I cannot figure out what went wrong with your installation (if anything). Please post the whole output.